# SherlockActionBar: tabs with fixed width

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I had a couple tabs in the Sherlock ActionBar, and everything was working fine, since each tab was resizing automatically till reaching the width of the phone.

Now, I added another tab and instead of resizing automatically, the tabs have the same fixed size than before, and thus the bar that contains the three bars is wider than the width of the phone.

Just like this:

[image]

and if we swipe to the right with our finger..

[image]

Is there any way I can reduce the size of each tab (or anyway that it's done automatically) so the tab bar occupies the width of the phone and we don't have to swipe?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was simply reduce the width of my images to 20 pixels (it could have been any number).
Android resizes to a higher size but not to a smaller size, so even if it would have been 10, 15 or any smaller value than the original size of the image used as the background of the tab, it would have stretched it correctly.